# VBA InStr always returning 0

Tags: vba, excel

I am using Excel 2010 and trying to make a function which will replace a part of the links in the Worksheet, depending on the user input. More specific I trying to replace the links to match the users Dropbox location.

This is the code I have so far

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim DropboxFolder As String
Dim SearchFor As String
Dim SearchPos As Integer

SearchFor = "Dropbox"

With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
.AllowMultiSelect = False
.Show
On Error Resume Next
DropboxFolder = .SelectedItems(1)
For Each theHyperLink In ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks
  SearchPos = InStr(0, SearchFor, theHyperLink.Address, vbBinaryCompare)
  theHyperLink.Address = DropboxFolder
  Next
Err.Clear
On Error GoTo 0
End With

End Sub
```

I have tried a debugging the code, and added a breakpoint at

```
SearchPos = InStr(0, SearchFor, theHyperLink.Address, vbBinaryCompare)
```

The SearchFor is `"Dropbox"`  and TheHyperLink.Address is `"..\Dropbox\Salgdanmarks Salgsakademi\1\Ny Microsoft Word Document.docx"`

But the SearchPos is set to `0`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `SearchPos = InStr(1, theHyperLink.Address, SearchFor, vbTextCompare)`

Comment: I think you have got `theHyperlink.address` and `searchFor` the other way around ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I realized that the comments are temporary so I am putting this as an answer. This will help any future visitors as well.

The syntax of `Instr` is

```
InStr([start, ]string1, string2[, compare])
```

The InStr function syntax has these arguments:

1. **start** (Optional). Numeric expression that sets the starting position for each search. If omitted, search begins at the first character position. If start contains Null, an error occurs. The start argument is required if compare is specified.
2. **string1** (Required). String expression **being searched**.
3. **string2** (Required). String expression **sought**.
4. **compare** (Optional). Specifies the type of string comparison. If compare is Null, an error occurs. If compare is omitted, the Option Compare setting determines the type of comparison. Specify a valid LCID (LocaleID) to use locale-specific rules in the comparison

So in your case you need to reverse your variables.

```
SearchPos = InStr(1, theHyperLink.Address, SearchFor, vbTextCompare)
```

Comment: @suddharth-rout Thanks a lot - I guess I need more coffee this morning. 

You made my day.

Comment: @denn he'll do that! :) Awesome to have Siddharth Rout (and many others) here! I've had my bacon saved a few times in the last few weeks alone! +1 to you both.